# Spark Streaming + Kafka: how to check name of topic from kafka message

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am using Spark Streaming to read from a list of Kafka Topics. 
I am following the official API at this [link](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-8-integration.html). The method I am using is:

```
val kafkaParams = Map("metadata.broker.list" -> configuration.getKafkaBrokersList(), "auto.offset.reset" -> "largest")
val topics = Set(configuration.getKafkaInputTopic())
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
            ssc, kafkaParams, topics)
```

I am wondering how will the executor read from the message from the list of topics ? What will be their policy? Will they read a topic and then when they finish the messages pass to the other topics?

And most importantly, how can I, after calling this method, check what is the topic of a message in the RDD?

```
stream.foreachRDD(rdd => rdd.map(t => {
        val key = t._1
        val json = t._2
        val topic = ???
})
```

Comment: You can use map like var records = stream.map(record => (record.topic))

Comment: @israel.zinc I think elements in `stream` are `Tuple2[String,String]`. There is no parameter or method called topic

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering how will the executor read from the message from the
>   list of topics ? What will be their policy? Will they read a topic and
>   then when they finish the messages pass to the other topics?

In the direct streaming approach, the driver is responsible for reading the offsets into the Kafka topics you want to consume. What it does it create a mapping between topics, partitions and the offsets that need to be read. After that happens, the driver assigns each worker a *range* to read into a specific Kafka topic. This means that if a single worker can run 2 tasks simultaneously (just for the sake of the example, it usually can run many more), then it can potentially read from two separate topics of Kafka concurrently.

> how can I, after calling this method, check what is the topic of a
>   message in the RDD?

You can use the overload of `createDirectStream` which takes a `MessageHandler[K, V]`:

```
val topicsToPartitions: Map[TopicAndPartition, Long] = ???

val stream: DStream[(String, String)] = 
  KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
        ssc, 
        kafkaParams, 
        topicsToPartitions,
        mam: MessageAndMetadata[String, String]) => (mam.topic(), mam.message())
```

Comment: Thank you @Yuval, but still. How can I access to the message AND topic while reading from Kafka. with `messageHandler` as parameter of `createDirectStream` it looks I can't anyway.

Comment: @salvob My code snippet does exactly that. The output would be a `DStream[(String, String)]`, where the first is the topic name.

Comment: Your code define a stream that supposedly contain message and topic for each record in it. 
But when I try to print the content of the tuple (with the snippet in my question - with a `println(key + topic + message) `, nothing happen. The method `rdd.count()` return the number of message correctly though

Comment: @salvob Did you try my snippet?

Comment: yes! With the difference that `topicsToPartitions` needs to be a Map. 
The stream I have is a `InputDStream` and not even a rdd.collect shows me the messages

Comment: And when you print `t._1`, what do you see? What do you mean by "nothing happens"? How are you running this? locally or inside a cluster?

Comment: Nothing, because it doesn't even enter into the rdd.map(...)
I run this locally.

Comment: Plus.. if I use a debugging tool for rdd it says that messageHandler has nothing to display

Comment: @salvob You see `count()` working fine but no message in `messageHandler`?

Comment: Hi @Yuval, thank you for coming back, yes! I figured it out the problem, it is an offset issue. In fact when I use a function like `collect`, it raises a `OutOfIndexOffset` or something like this. The first time I set it to 0L, but that offset doesn't exist in that Kafka topic. But.. I am wondering, why the `count()` works? if there are no messages in that range of offsets?

Comment: @salvob If you don't explicitly set the offset, it starts either from the earliest offset or latest, depending on if you passed the `auto.offset.reset` flag to earliest or latest

Comment: if I use createDirectStream with messageHandler, it explicitly need the offsets

Comment: @salvob I know, I was talking about what happens when you don't use the message handler. Are you storing offsets somewhere prior to invoking this? Because that's what you'll have to do in order to trigger this overload every time.

Comment: I do store them, but my problem is how do I get them the very first time? and more or less the answere is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43281893/kafka-and-spark-get-first-offset-of-a-topic-via-api/43286596#43286596). But if I force the starting offset to 0L, it raises an `OutOfIndexOffset` error, but I am wondering why the `count()` function return somethings, if there are no messages in that offsets ?