# kafka and Spark: Get first offset of a topic via API

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am playing with Spark Streaming and Kafka (with the Scala API), and would like to read message from a set of Kafka topics with Spark Streaming.

The following method:

```
val kafkaParams = Map("metadata.broker.list" -> configuration.getKafkaBrokersList(), "auto.offset.reset" -> "smallest")
KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topics)
```

reads from Kafka to the latest available offset, but doesn't give me the metadata that I need (since I am reading from a set of topics, I need for every message I read that topic) but this other method `KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder, Tuple2[String, String]](ssc, kafkaParams, currentOffsets, messageHandler)` wants explicitly an offset that I don't have.

I know that there is this shell command that gives you the last offset.

```
kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell 
  --broker-list <broker>:  <port> 
  --topic <topic-name> --time -1 --offsets 1
```

and `KafkaCluster.scala` is an API that is for developers that used to be public and gives you exactly what I would like.

Hint?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the code from GetOffsetShell.scala [kafka API documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/A+Guide+To+The+Kafka+Protocol#AGuideToTheKafkaProtocol-OffsetAPI)

```
val consumer = new SimpleConsumer(leader.host, leader.port, 10000, 100000, clientId)
val topicAndPartition = TopicAndPartition(topic, partitionId)
val request = OffsetRequest(Map(topicAndPartition -> PartitionOffsetRequestInfo(time, nOffsets)))
val offsets = consumer.getOffsetsBefore(request).partitionErrorAndOffsets(topicAndPartition).offsets
```

Or you can create new consumer with unique groupId and use it for getting first offset

```
val consumer=new KafkaConsumer[String, String](createConsumerConfig(config.brokerList))
consumer.partitionsFor(config.topic).foreach(pi => {
      val topicPartition = new TopicPartition(pi.topic(), pi.partition())

      consumer.assign(List(topicPartition))
      consumer.seekToBeginning()
      val firstOffset = consumer.position(topicPartition)
 ...
```

Comment: Thank you @Natalia! 
In the first snippet .. what is time? and what is `time` and what is `nOffset` ?

Comment: Oh I see, you got the first snippet from [here](https://github.com/kafka-dev/kafka/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/GetOffsetShell.scala)

Comment: @salvob was this question answered correctly? if so, please marked as an answered question, otherwise I will appreciate if you can tell us how you solved the problem :)

Comment: Unfortunately not, I could not get the smallest kafka offset and get the topic from it. We ended up writing another module in order to read from a different kafka topic. There aren't good example that deal data from different topics in different ways. Please let me know if you find any solution. Thank you